# <Class> Object has no attribute <attribute_name>

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So, i'm new to python and been stuck many hours facing an error when trying run the code bellow

```
class ConjuntoDeInteiros:
    def _init_(self, conjunto, storage_capacity=100): #initializes a list and its length, default value is 100
        self.storage_capacity = storage_capacity
        self.conjunto = [None] * storage_capacity

    def addElement(self, intNumber): #add an element to the list
        self.conjunto.append(intNumber)

    def union(self, instanceOfConjuntoDeInteiros): #returns the union of an instance list with another instance list
        return self.conjunto + instanceOfConjuntoDeInteiros

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = ConjuntoDeInteiros()
    c2 = ConjuntoDeInteiros()
    c1.addElement(10)
    c2.addElement(5)
    c1.union(c2)
```

error: *Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 15, in 
File "", line 7, in addElement
AttributeError: 'ConjuntoDeInteiros' object has no attribute 'conjunto'*

What am i doing wrong???

Comment: `_init_` -> `__init__`, use *two underscores* on each side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `init` function is wrong. It needs to be `__init__` and you have `_init_`. Therefore your `self.conjunto` is never defined and hence your error. You also have `conjunto` and `storage_capacity` as parameters of `__init__`, but you don't pass them when creating `ConjuntoDeInteiros()`.

Comment: Not really necessary because the **Python** *constructor* works in that way.

Comment: @jezza_99 Thank you!!! It worked! I didn't noticed the typo ahaha

Comment: @h.devillefletcher I understand that you can call `parameter=value` in `__init__`, but `conjunto` still requires a user parameter as it isn't defined

Comment: that`s right! and might not be a necessary parameter in this case...

Answer (score 2):

The error that it shows you is caused because you are trying to add an instance of class `ConjuntoDeInterios()`, if you want to join the **list** of the other class with the current defined **class** you need to overload the `operator+` on `ConjuntoDeInterios()` by this way:

```
class ConjuntoDeInteiros:
    def __init__(self, conjunto=[None], storage_capacity=100): #initializes a list and its length, default value is 100
        self.storage_capacity = storage_capacity
        self.conjunto = [None] * storage_capacity

    # overload operator (+)
    def __add__(self, instanceOfConjuntoDeInteiros): # returns the union of an instance list with another instance list
        return self.conjunto + instanceOfConjuntoDeInteiros.conjunto

    def addElement(self, intNumber): # add an element to the list
        self.conjunto.append(intNumber)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = ConjuntoDeInteiros()
    c2 = ConjuntoDeInteiros()
    c1.addElement(10)
    c2.addElement(5)
    print(c1 + c2)
```

```
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 None, None, 10,   None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
 None, None, None, None, None, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
class ConjuntoDeInteiros:
    def _init_(self, conjunto, storage_capacity=100): #initializes a list and its length, default value is 100
        self.storage_capacity = storage_capacity
        self.conjunto = [None] * storage_capacity
```

Your code needs to define conjunto in self.conjunto. Otherwise it won't recognize conjunto.